# Passing value in IEnumerable method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

net mvc c#. I have created model for view. I can receive all rows from the table but when I try to pass value in method which is return list is not working 
  Here is my code
Controller class

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TechnicianDBO db = new TechnicianDBO();
    List<Technician> technicians = db.technicians.ToList();
    return View(technicians);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int Postcode)
{
    TechnicianDBO db = new TechnicianDBO();
    List<Technician> technicians = db.Jobtechnicians(Postcode).ToList();
    return View(technicians);
}
```

Db class

```
public IEnumerable<Technician> Jobtechnicians(int postcode)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnect"].ConnectionString;
    List<Technician> Jobtechnicians = new List<Technician>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetTechnicianByPostcode", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlParameter paramId = new SqlParameter();
        paramId.ParameterName = "@postcode";
        paramId.Value = postcode;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Technician technician = new Technician();
            technician.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["techId"]);
            // technician.Username = dr["techUsername"].ToString();
            technician.Firstname = dr["techFirstname"].ToString();
            technician.Lastname = dr["techLastname"].ToString();
            technician.LandlineNo = dr["landlineNo"].ToString();
            technician.MobileNo = dr["mobileNo"].ToString();
            technician.Address1 = dr["address1"].ToString();
            technician.Address2 = dr["address2"].ToString();
            technician.Postcode = Convert.ToInt32(dr["postcode"]);
            technician.Email = dr["email"].ToString();
            technician.Fax = dr["fax"].ToString();
            technician.Profession = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ProfessionId"]);
            Jobtechnicians.Add(technician);
        }

        return Jobtechnicians;
    }
}
```

Comment: "not working" is not a particularly good description of the problem. Are you seeing any errors or is it just not returning any results? If it's the latter, are you sure that your stored procedure actually returns results for the specified parameter?

Comment: Can you post what exactly happens?
I mean an exception or whatever error is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give `CommandType`

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetTechnicianByPostcode", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

and also when you call `.ToString()` you better check whether that column value null or not if that column allow null in your table

Comment: Make sense Thank you very much Damith its working now.Sorry for this question cuz I Didnt catch exception that is why I was kept changing the controller code.